# populating thymeleaf dropdown with data of another table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i'm new to spring-boot. In my system there are two models named subject,course(two databases with the same names and connected by the foreign key course_id).I need to make it possible to select course name in a dropdown list in the addSubject thymeleaf form. Can someone please tell me how to do this

Subject.DAO file

```
@Service
public class SubjectDAO {

    @Autowired
    SubjectRepository subjectRepository;

    //to save a subject
    public Subject save(Subject subject){
        return subjectRepository.save(subject);
    }

    //to search all subjects
    public List<Subject> findAll(){
        return subjectRepository.findAll();
    }

    //get a subject by id
    public Subject findById(Long id){
        return subjectRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }


    //delete a subject
    public void delete(Long id){
        subjectRepository.deleteById(id);
    }


}
```

Course.DAO file

```
@Service
public class CourseDAO {

    @Autowired
    CourseRepository courseRepository;

    //to save a course
    public Course save(Course course){
        return courseRepository.save(course);
    }

    //to search all courses
    public List<Course> findAll(){
        return courseRepository.findAll();
    }

    //get a course by id
    public Course findById(Long id){
        return courseRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }


    //delete a course
    public void delete(Long id){
        courseRepository.deleteById(id);
    }


}
```

Subject Controller

```
@Controller
public class SubjectController {
    @Autowired
    private SubjectDAO subjectDAO;

    @RequestMapping("/subject")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model){
        List<Subject> subjectDetails= subjectDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("subjectDetails",subjectDetails);
        return "subject";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/subject/new")
    public String addSubject(Model model){
        Subject subject =new Subject();
        model.addAttribute("subject",subject);
        return "addSubject";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/subject/save",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveCourse(@ModelAttribute("subject") Subject subject){
        subjectDAO.save(subject);
        return  "redirect:/subject";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/subject/edit/{id}")
    public ModelAndView updateSubjcet(@PathVariable(name="id")Long id){
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView(("updateSubject"));

        Subject subject=subjectDAO.findById(id);
        mav.addObject("subject",subject);
        return  mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/subject/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable(name="id") Long id){
        subjectDAO.delete(id);
        return  "redirect:/subject";
    }
}
```

Subject html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Adding a Subject</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h1>Add a new Subject</h1>
    <br/>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/subject/save}" th:object="${subject}" method="post">
        <table border="0" cell[adding="10">
            <tr>
                <td>Subject code:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{course_code}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Subject Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Course:</td>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value=""></option>

                    </select>
                    Z
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><button type="submit">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://github.com/Ayesh17/attendance this is github repo of the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to load Course combo inside subject html

You need to modify subject controller

```
@RequestMapping("/subject")
public String viewHomePage(Model model){
    List<Subject> subjectDetails= subjectDAO.findAll();
    List<Course> courseDetail= courseDAO.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("subjectDetails",subjectDetails);
    model.addAttribute("courses",courseDetail);
    return "subject";
}
```

In HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>Course:</td>
    <td>
        <select th:field="*{course_code}">
          <option value="">Choose..</option>
          <option th:each="course: ${courses}" th:value="${course.id}" th:text="${course.name}" />
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

**Edit 1:**

I think you are loading `addSubject.html`

In that case you need to modify addSubject controller

```
@RequestMapping("/subject/new")
public String addSubject(Model model){
    Subject subject =new Subject();
    model.addAttribute("subject",subject);
    List<Course> courseDetail= courseDAO.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("courses",courseDetail);
    return "addSubject";
}
```

Edit 2:

As per your code in Git I can see

```
@Autowired
private SubjectDAO subjectDAO;
private CourseDAO courseDAO;
```

It should be

```
 @Autowired
 private SubjectDAO subjectDAO;

 @Autowired
 private CourseDAO courseDAO;
```

Comment: tried this but got an error An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/addSubject.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/addSubject.html]")

Comment: I think HTMl you added is addSubject ..  I have added mroe detail Please try

Comment: hi thx a lot but still its not working.this time got a NullPointException            There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No message available
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.project.attendance.controller.SubjectController.addSubject(SubjectController.java:37) 37-        List<Course> courseDetail= courseDAO.findAll();

Comment: yh i think it was null and now NullPointException gone but showing previous error again 'An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/addSubject.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/addSubject.html]")

Comment: attribute in html and controller should be same.   model.addAttribute("courses",courseDetail);  I think you have added "course" in controller code also in html <select th:field="*{co}">

Comment: hey still it shows the same error and i have added changed code to git

Comment: other than this line change "<option th:each="co: ${courses}" th:value="${co.id}" th:text="${co.name}" />"   I don't see any other issue. Please check courseDetail value also.

Comment: please add exception log

Comment: how can i add an exception log?

Comment: You can edit question else upload in Git as seperate file and share link

Comment: Error is there in exception "Invalid property 'co' of bean class [com.project.attendance.model.Subject]: Bean property 'co' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter? at "    Try the edited HTML.

Comment: had  to change<select th:field="*{course}"> to <select th:field="*{course_code}">. Because there is no property called course in the Subject entity and it worked.thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

First add all courses to the ModelMap

```
model.addAttribute("cources",courseDao.findAll());
```

Then use `th:each` attribute to populate select options

```
<select th:field="*{course}">
  <option value="">Choose..</option>
  <option th:each="c: ${cources}" th:value="${c.id}" th:text="${c.name}" />
</select>
```

Comment: by the modelMap did u mean subjectController?

Comment: No i meant Model